# How to Select multiple tables for converting mysql to json?

Tags: php, mysql, json

How to Convert mysql all tables to json(How to Select Multiple tables, not one);

I am trying to select multiple table of my db:
then convert it from mysql to json format
Please guide me!

```
  <body>  
       <?php   
       $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "martlink_db");  
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";  
       $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
       $json_array = array();  
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
       {  
            $json_array[] = $row;  
       }  
       echo '<pre>';  
       print_r(json_encode($json_array));  
       echo '</pre>'; 
       //echo json_encode($json_array);  
       ?>  
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following query

```
<?php   
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "martlink_db");  
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM table1 t1,table2 t2 where condition"  
    $stmt = $conn->query($sql);
    $jsonArr = array();
    do 
    {
        $rowset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        if ($rowset) 
          {
            $jsonArr[] = tojson($rowset, $i);
          }
    }while ($stmt->nextRowset()); 
?>
```